# Netbeans 6.9 startup error javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: netbeans, nullpointerexception, startup-error

I have Netbeans 6.9 installed. Suddenly it doesn't start. It gives me an error..

**`javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:java.lang.NullPointerException`**

This is just one line error, occurs when creating a new project.. at the time when I select frameworks on which I want to make my project...  Please help to get me out of this error.. I have searched a lot of time.. but no luck... Any help will be appreciated..Thank you.

Comment: your best bet is to install an newer version of NB. 7.2 is very stable

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,  I have downloaded netbeans 7.1.2.. I have tried all of the versions, but i am still getting Same error while creating new project. HElP plz...

Comment: please post some info about the environment, OS, 64 or 32 bit, java version

Comment: Netbeans 7.1.2 , Jdk7, Jre7, Windows 7, 64-bit version..

Comment: Hey.. I have Jdk 7 installed.. then i went to jdk 6.. then installed netbeans 6.9 again.. now everything works perfect !! Don't know where the problem is?? But now its gone. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: good, maybe you can add it as an answer and accept it so that others who come across this error get helped

Comment: Well, I am sorry, I m new to StackOverflow... How can i do it?

Comment: below is a button that says 'answer your own question'. And write up all the details and steps you did to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already installed Jdk 7 .. then now I went back to JDK6.. then installed netbeans 6.9 again.. now Everything works perfect !! Don't know where the problem is?? But now its gone.